# How to validate multiple conditions for one field in Yup?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

I am using Formik and Yup for valdiation.
I have this validation schema and the field "listType" can have 3 values [0, 1, 2]. I want to make 3 different conditions for each value of listType and put different validations based on the value

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  listType: Yup.string().required('Type is required'),
  values: Yup.array().when('listType', {
    is: (listType) => listType == 0,
    then: Yup.array().of(
      Yup.string()
        .matches(macAdressRegex, 'Please enter valid MAC Addresses')
        .required('Field is required'),
    ),
  }),
});
```

I want to validate also when listType value==1 and value==2 and put different regex validation for each one of them, but I can't find a way to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.test` function:

```
const validationSchema = yup.object({
    listType: yup.string().required('Type is required'),
    values: yup.array().test('values-test', 'dummy message', (value, validationContext) => {
        const {
            createError,
            parent: {
                listType,
            },
        } = validationContext;

        if (listType === 0 && value === 'some value') {
            return createError({ message: 'listType = 1, ' + value });
        }

        if (listType === 3 && value === 'some value') {
            return createError({ message: 'listType = 3, ' + value });
        }

        return true;
    }),
});
```